# get a few selected option javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I get the selected value from a dropdown list in case there are more than one selected item using JavaScript? For example:

```
<select name"nana" id="nana">
  <option value="0"</option>
  <option value="1"</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2"</option>
  <option value="3"</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4"</option>
</select>
```

I tried:

```
var e = document.getElementById("nana");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

and

```
document.querySelector("nana").value;
```

but it returns only the first selected value (2). How can I get all of the selected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add multiple="multiple" for multiple for more than 1 select

```js
var selectNana = document.getElementById("nana");
    var selectedNana = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < selectNana.length; i++) {
        if (selectNana.options[i].selected) selectedNana.push(selectNana.options[i].value);
    }
    console.log(selectedNana);
```

```html
<select name"nana" id="nana" multiple="multiple" >
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your HTML syntax is correct - open tags, like `<option`, need closing `>`s too.

Use the query string `#nana > option[selected]` to select children with the selected attribute, then map to their values:

```js
const selectedValues = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('#nana > option[selected]'),
  option => option.value
);
console.log(selectedValues);
```

```html
<select name="nana" id="nana">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1"></option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2"></option>
  <option value="3"></option>
  <option selected="selected" value="4"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I used your script and its work well. Thank you very much!